# R Regex Repetition

Tags: r, regex

Working through R4DS Strings chapter and am getting confused about the following regular expression example:

```
x <- "1888 is the longest year in Roman numerals: MDCCCLXXXVIII"

str_view(x, "C?")
```

This code returns no match

Using the `?` I understand specifies either match 0 or 1 time and repetition is "greedy" and will match the longest string possible, so why isn't 1 "C" matched?

Additionally, the below code matches the first "CC":

```
x <- "1888 is the longest year in Roman numerals: MDCCCLXXXVIII"

str_view(x, "CC?")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it does return a match, but it's the empty string.

Explanation:

1. The regex engine starts by checking if the first character matches
2. `M` does not match `C`.
3. But wait, the `C` is optional.
4. The empty string matches.
5. Success!

On the other hand `CC?` can't match at the start of the string, so the engine has to step through the string until it finds the first `C`, and will then match regardless of how many `C`s there are.

Moral: Never construct a regex where all tokens are optional, allowing an empty match (unless you're planning to do exactly that).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I understand my regex of simply `C?` was a bit odd, but I was curious to understand why it returned the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the regex engine will give up if it can.  With just a single optional character you aren't neccessarily asking for anything.  The regex is satisfied at position 0, the "C" is tried and not found, but is optional.

With the two characters, the hard "C" forces the engine to move to the right, since you're actually asking for something, and the second "C" gets thrown in since it's the next (optional) character.

Answer (score 2):

There is a match for `str_view(x, "C?")`, but it has length 0. It is helpful to analyze this behavior with base R's function `regexpr`.

```
regexpr("C?", x)
# [1] 1
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 0
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

This tells that the match starts at position 1 and has a length of 0. Since `C?` means `C` one time or zero times, it matches the empty string at the beginning of `x`.

```
regexpr("CC?", x)
# [1] 47
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 2
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

In contrast, the regex `CC?` matches a string starting at position 47 with length 2. Since the first `C` is necessary, it cannot match the empty string. Since `?` is greedy, `CC?` matches both the first and the second `C` of `x`.

Comment: Very helpful, I definitely get it now. Thank you